# based on excel4node want to disable column unhide option of excel

Tags: node.js, excel4node

Is there any option in excel4node package where we can disable option for unhide column?

similar like below image
https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-blog/unhide-columns/excel-unhide-column-disabled.png

Once I hide column from code user should not allowed to unhide column what I am searching in excel4node.